# Repair damage from dog scratching wooden door

Tags: repair, wood, doors

I've recently moved from the city to the countryside and my dog is having a bit of trouble getting used to the shooting that happens near our house.

Unfortunately, while we were out yesterday he seems to have become particularly stressed and has absolutely trashed my double doors.

[image: door damage]

I know I could sand and revarnish the flat parts of the door, but even then some of the scratches might be too deep for that. I'd have no idea how to fix the raised strip though.

Is there anything I can do here short of replacing the doors?

---

Edit: This is what that strip looks like from above.

[image]

Comment: Sanding, wood filler or bondo, paint/stain.  The raised strip should only be held on by small finishing nails and should be easy to take off.   Nothing better than enjoying a morning cup of coffee and listening to the gentle sounds of gun shots(sarcasm)

Comment: Like @crip659 says, bondo etc, but I suspect that the thing in the middle is a t-shaped astragal and those are complicated to reproduce and install. So… patch and paint. And give the good doggo a scritch behind the ears from me.

Comment: sand, varnish and clear coats.  it doesn't look that bad.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - How do I check whether it's a simple strip or an astragal? (I have no idea what the latter is) I think I'd struggle to fill in the gouges well enough to keep the shape...

Comment: Take a picture from the top. It should be pretty clear if it’s just trim versus a built-up t shaped thing that has around 1/2” of thickness on the door edge.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, I've added a photo... It doesn't look like it's just a strip, but is this something I should be able to just buy?

Comment: You can buy the wooden piece, but then you'd have to stain and finish it to match the door.. Easier to just refinish what's there; it looks like the scratches are just in the clear coat so you may not even need to do more than sand lightly with fine sandpaper and apply another layer of varnish to the damaged area.

Comment: @keshlam - Some of the scratches are well into the wood, a good couple of mm in places, there was quite an amount on the floor, so sadly it's not just the clear coat... I've resigned myself that I'm going to need to sand down, fill and refinish the rest of the frame, so doing so to the wooden piece too is no biggy... I'd just need to know what it's called so I can find it?

Comment: It's probably just described as a hardwood molding of the appropriate width with rounded/bullnose sides.

Comment: Lucky you! That’s an easy (-ish) to find piece of trim. You can do the weatherstripping in a less complicated way. I’d remove it and bring it to either a door/window supplier or a good lumberyard.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - Any idea what it might be called? I'm really struggling to find anything similar on diy.com or wickes.co.uk and due to where I live, I don't have a whole lot of other options (can order online if I need to though). Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: Really not sure how I'd name it, especially in the UK. (This is what I thought it was: https://www.bairdbrothers.com/1-34-Ash-T-Astragal-B935B-P14172.aspx )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short term solution is to repair the damage as other said.

Sanding, wood filler, sand again then paint/stain.

Longer term solution (prevention) install metal stripes to protect the wood. You can find the proper size at hardware store, some are glue on some use small nails/screws.

None of the above will protect the dog from stress, just protect the door.

To protect the dog, install remote controlled dog entry, so you can let him in while you are not at home. Or another type that works with they collar so only the dog can enter or exit.

[smart dog](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000WJ0IGA)

Comment: He's actually been getting used to the hunters pretty quickly, I guess they were just too close to the house for his liking at the same time with us being out... Hopefully he settles in soon or we'll have to work out something else. Unfortunately, it's a rental, so I can't just go and replace the door to put in a flap. Screw in metal strips might not be a bad option though. With the sanding and wood filler, will it be easy enough to keep the shape of that strip down the middle or will that need replacing?

Answer (score 0):

Astragal are common mouldings. I would replace the whole piece.

Comment: Please enhance your answer with more details, otherwise it may get deleted.

Comment: What part needs more explaining?